# is were way to disable LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer

Tags: variables, playframework, local, playframework-1.x

Is there way to disable `LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer` for my controllers in playframework in 1.2.4/5

Preferably by setting configuration parameter?

My problem is that it causes a lot of issues with JPA. I used to use older versions of play and my app worked well but since introduction this enhancer it produces weird errors here and there. I am tired of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible. In CorePlugin.enhance method the enhancer is added without any condition and in LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass method there is no disable flag.

A workaround for you could be to put problematic code in another class that does not inherit from Controller and call it by delegation in your controller

Comment: yes thank you. I looked at source code of Controller and found out that there is no way to disable it. Not sure I did it right but I completely removed the interface from the controller declaration and recompiled play framework. at least my issues with JPA and different kinds of relationships were solved. Do you know if my solutiuon has some downsides?

Comment: LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer is used to provid await functionalities in controllers so if you don't use await I guess there is no side effect

Answer (score 0):

If you include "$" at the end of a method name it will turn off local variable names enhancements for this method.

Comment: I am not sure it works. Tried it and it didn't help. Also source code doesn't seem to have any proves of this